# How to prevent OCaml batteries from overriding values

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-batteries

The package Batteries.Num overrides the functions (+), (-), ... So the compiler gives an error on the following simple code

```
open Batteries
open Num
let a = 4 + 4;;
```

File "a.ml", line 3, characters 8-9:
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         Batteries.Num.num = Num.num

I compile with "ocamlfind ocamlc -package batteries a.ml".

EDIT: I know I could use Pervasives.(+) or just open Num locally.

But I am able to compile this program successfully with ocamlbuild with the simplest _tags file: 
    <*>: pkg_batteries, package(batteries), package(num)

Where is the magic? How can I compile like ocamlbuild does with a Makefile?

EDIT: I found the solution. I actually had two versions of batteries (1.4 and 2.2), and ocamlfind gave the version 2.2 on command line, and 1.4 on ocamlbuild. I don't know why. I believe the early version of batteries didn't redefine the module Num (but you had to use BatNum), so the problem doesn't occur with the older version. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

What command are you using the build it? Because if you aren't specifying a build *target* (i.e. your command is `ocamlbuild a.ml` instead of `ocamlbuild a.ml a.native`) it will appear as though its compiling even though it isn't.

What is ACTUALLY happening when you try  "ocamlfind ocamlc -package batteries a.ml" is that the `+` from nums is overshadowing the `+` from Pervasives.

You could do `let a = Pervasives.(+) 4 4;;`, or instead of opening Nums, do `Nums.` for everything like that.

Comment: Yes, I know I could use Pervasives.(+), or just use let open Num in whenever necessary. My problem is that I have a code that compiles fine with ocamlbuild, but not on command line (or a Makefile).
I use "ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind a.byte" which does produce an executable, and again "ocamlfind ocamlc -package batteries a.ml" gives a type error.

Basically I have a larger project that compiles fine with ocamlbuild, but I need to switch to OCamlMakefile which fails for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can just refer to the function by using the module name you want.

If you want the `(+)` from `Pervasives`, you just say `Pervasives.(+) x y` instead of `x + y`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have used when I faced this problem is to open Pervasive to override Batteries values.

```
open Batteries
open Num
open Pervasives

let a = 4 + 4;;
```